# What is a "birch rope bed"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I guess that the first meaning of "rope" is something like a "cable", but in this context, is "rope" the wooden structure of this bed? 
I think that this bed has a birch-wooden decoration on its structure, is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! What is the context, Stephanie?

Comment: My guess is that a "birch rope bed" is a "rope bed" whose frame uses birch wood as material. A "[rope bed](https://www.gcv.org/Our-Blog/entryid/295)" is likely a bed whose mattress is supported by a network of ropes.

Comment: Thanks. This is a description of a hotel room: it describes an old-fashioned room with "antique birch rope bed".

Comment: This question does not appear to be about learning the English language within the scope defined in the help center. As interesting as the question is...

Comment: Thanks. I've adjusted my answer. More logical for a room advertisement. w.o. context I was thinking along lines of "history" and "native".. VTC as off-topic.

Comment: I guess one can make rope of a sort out of bark. But I'm not sure if that is what birch here refers to. It is probably easier to make a bed frame out of birchwood than to make "birch rope" out of birchbark. But I'm not familiar with the historical usage. Did pioneers go around making rope out of bark? I've not heard of it.

Comment: Oh how twisted our brains work... This year my daughter's theme in pre-school is "Indians", so we deal with lots ("loads", actually) of things feathery and crafty and nature-y every day. Got me on the wrong track, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you. I am a translator and I needed to know how do a native English speaker understand this expression. It is the first time I use this interesting website... do you think my question was to post in "English language and usage" instead of "English language learner"? I understand that the "birch rope bed" can appear not very interesting!!

Comment: Hello Stephanie & welcome. Have you read the help pages on how this site works and what questions are on- or off-topic? (Just a warning with you being a translator and such.) IMHO, ELL is the more "relaxed" site as far as the range of accepted questions is concerned. Still, plain requests for translation are frowned upon here, too. Give us context and show that you did your own research, and we'll be happy to help. Some say the guys over at ELU are rather "harsh" at times, but many users have accounts on both sites. The focus differs a bit between ELL and ELU, but there is also some overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A [rope bed](https://www.google.de/search?q=rope%20bed&biw=1349&bih=843&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=pgO1VOuLBsPdaubMAg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ) is an old-fashioned style of beds that uses ropes (instead of wooden slats) to support the mattress.
- Birch bark can be used to make ropes, but most likely the term "birch" refers to the wood of the frame.